# Why is Heroku unable to find my "manage.py" file in the Django app I'm trying to deploy?

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I deploy my Django app on Heroku I get this:

[image: One dyno running then heroku ps and then no dynos running]

As you can see it says that there is a dyno running and then when I enter "heroku ps" it says that no dynos are running.

"herokeroku ps eroku ps" is just a glitch in the CLI.

I checked the logs and it said that the deployment failed and in the release logs of that deployment it says it can't find the "manage.py" file. However, the "manage.py" file is there in the root folder and the Heroku branch is up to date.

I can run the app locally with "heroku local".

Do you know why Heroku might not be able to find a "manage.py" file?

Thank you